# ACPI errors filing syslog

Tags: kernel, acpi

I have a dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 HP Pavillion wave 600-A051a. The syslog and kern.log are filling rapidly with this error which seems to be the same thing

```
Nov  2 15:18:18 Wave kernel: [25910.177957] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psargs-359)
Nov  2 15:18:18 Wave kernel: [25910.177960] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff9e29778e45f0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)
Nov  2 15:18:18 Wave kernel: [25910.177963] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20160930/evgpe-646)
```

What can I do to fix it please?